# Codeigniter helper with model data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Instead of repetitive data pasting into my controllers, I am looking to create a helper called "navigation" this will be used for every controller and load in the navigation subviews.

Currently, in EVERY controller I am adding the following code.

```
// Get Subcategories
$subcat1 = $this->Categories_model->get_artstyles();
$subcat2 = $this->Categories_model->get_artsubjects();
$subcat3 = $this->Categories_model->get_media();
$subcat4 = $this->Categories_model->get_photography();

$this->view_data['sub_cat1'] = $subcat1->result();
$this->view_data['sub_cat2'] = $subcat2->result();
$this->view_data['sub_cat3'] = $subcat3->result();
$this->view_data['sub_cat4'] = $subcat4->result();
```

So what I would like to do is trim this down and load that data as a helper. So ultimately all I do in each controller is load the helper.

If you feel this is the wrong way to do it, please advise as I'm still a little unsure on CI and its ways.

Those 4 subcat variables are all wanting to be global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this data is relevant to all your controllers, you should extend the CI_Controller like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
     protected $view_data;

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();         
                 $this->load->helper('nav');
                 $this->view_data = load_navigation();
     }
}
```

Place this file inside the `core` directory and extend all your controllers like this:

```
class CONTROLLER_NAME extends MY_Controller
```

Read more [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html).

In the helper function:

```
function load_navigation() {
         $CI =& get_instance();
         $CI->load->model('Categories_model');
         $result['sub_cat1'] = $CI->Categories_model->get_artstyles()->result();
         $result['sub_cat2'] = $CI->Categories_model->get_artsubjects()->result();
         $result['sub_cat3'] = $CI->Categories_model->get_media()->result();
         $result['sub_cat4'] = $CI->Categories_model->get_photography()->result(); 
         return $result;
```

}

EDIT:

In order to load the variable into the view:

```
$data['view_data'] = $this->view_data;
$this->load->view('MY_VIEW', $data);
```

In the view you can access it like this: `$view_data`.

Comment: Is the helper function the alternative to extending the Controller? The reason I ask is the version of CI is 1.7.9 which doesnt have a core folder

Comment: You can extend controllers in 1.7. Its just a different directory. Read here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller/

Comment: Thanks for that. Now just getting undefined variable in my views. I have created MY_Controller under libraries/MY_Controller and helper "nav_helper" under helpers/nav_helper

Comment: That view_data just doesnt seem to be getting passed to the view.

I have created a pastebin. In the order of MY_Controller, nav_helper and Homecontroller.. http://pastebin.com/GCNhbSXq

Comment: Move the contents of `__construct` to the `MY_Controller()` function and remove `parent::__construct();` which is relevant to CI 2.0 and higher.

Comment: Sorry I am lost.. The wiki doesnt seem to be helping :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12383/discussion-between-yan-and-stublackett)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a html templating system, and have it in the default html template as standard.

I use the template library from [Williams Concepts](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/)